# Rofi leaves unresponsive terminals after run-shell-command | `Q` or `Ctrl-C` don't work

Tags: i3, launcher, dmenu, rofi

I'm trying to switch from using `dmenu` to `rofi` on my system, on which
I use `i3wm`. I have the following keybinding:

```
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+d exec --no-startup-id rofi -combi-modi
window#drun#run -show combi -show-icons
```

I use `urxvt` as my default terminal, and it's the one that's specified
in my `config.rasi` file for `rofi` to use.

The problem I have is when I launch `rofi`, and try to do something like
`htop SHIFT RET` to run `htop` in a terminal window.

When I'm done with `htop`, I hit `Q` and the process ends, but I'm left
with a blank terminal window. Hitting `Q` again doesn't kill it, nor
does `Ctrl-C`. I have to kill the window via my i3 keybinding
`$mod+Shift+Q`.

It's a similar situation with a command like `neofetch`, or `ls -l`,
except now the first `Q` doesn't kill the process as it has already
completed – the terminal window is not blank but contains the output of
those commands.

My `run-shell-command` is `"{terminal} -hold -e {cmd}"`.

I don't get this behavior when running these commands via `dmenu`. For
instance, `htop` is in the `dmenu-recent/terminal` file, and hitting `Q`
kills the process and the terminal window at the same time. This is the
behavior I would like to replicate with `rofi` – is this possible?

Comment: I'm not on a machine with rxvt-unicode right now, but the behavior you describe seems to be exactly what `-hold` is documented to achieve: -hold|+hold -- Turn on/off hold window after exit support. If enabled, urxvt will not immediately destroy its window when the program executed within it exits. Instead, it will wait till it is being killed or closed by the user; resource hold. (from http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/rxvt-unicode/doc/rxvt.1.pod). Have you tried removing the -hold flag?

Comment: @Wieland Yes -- removing the '-hold' flag allows me to kill both the terminal window and the running process of `htop` with a single hit of `Q`. But running `neofetch` or another command that just outputs something leads to the command executing and the terminal immediately closing by itself -- not desirable.

Comment: @Wieland But checking again, this seems to be the behavior of `dmenu` -- running `neofetch` as `terminal` or `terminal-hold` leads to the terminal window immediately closing after execution. So maybe there is no way around this: if we are to run shell commands via `rofi`, we have to accept that the terminal window has to be "manually" closed.